# Send custom field to Paypal failed

Tags: php, paypal

Since I can't get the user ID through $_SESSION in the paypal IPN file, I'm trying to send the username ID - the user who bought the service through `custom` field.

buy.php code: (buy.php -> Paypal -> ipn.php)

```
$sendPayData = array(
                "METHOD" => "BMCreateButton",
                "VERSION" => "65.2",
                "USER" => "UserApi",
                "PWD" => "PwdAPI",
                "SIGNATURE" => "SignatureAPI",
                "BUTTONCODE" => "ENCRYPTED",
                "BUTTONTYPE" => "BUYNOW",
                "BUTTONSUBTYPE" => "SERVICES",
                "BUTTONCOUNTRY" => "US",
                "BUTTONIMAGE" => "reg",
                "BUYNOWTEXT" => "BUYNOW",
                "L_BUTTONVAR0" => "custom=".$_SESSION['ID'],
                "L_BUTTONVAR1" => "item_number=1",
                "L_BUTTONVAR2" => "item_name=API Plan",
                "L_BUTTONVAR3" => "amount=10",
                "L_BUTTONVAR4" => "currency_code=USD",
                "L_BUTTONVAR5" => "no_shipping=1",
                "L_BUTTONVAR6" => "no_note=1",
                "L_BUTTONVAR7" => "notify_url=http://IPNLOCATION/IPN.PHP",
                "L_BUTTONVAR8" => "cancel_return=http:/website.com/purchase.php",
                "L_BUTTONVAR9" => "return=http://website.com/purchase.php"

            );


            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?'.http_build_query($sendPayData));
            $nvpPayReturn = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
```

When the request is processed through Paypal it says:
"We were unable to decrypt the certificate id."
Any ideas ?

Comment: I think this problem is produced when you don't copy the HTML button source perfectly. I've seen cases where some extra `<div>` produced this error.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.
I've just fixed the problem.
The problem is because of my regex to extract the PKCS7, it seems like paypal adds '=' operator when I send the custom field, which wasn't included in my regex.

instead of:
if(preg_match('/(?<pkcs7>[a-zA-Z0-9+\/]{2000,})/',$nvpPayReturn,$results))

I changed to:
if(preg_match('/(?<pkcs7>[a-zA-Z0-9+\/=]{2000,})/',$nvpPayReturn,$results))

By the way: is that regex good to extract the pkcs7 code ?